# React default prop overwriting state change in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state property in the `Child` component called `fullWindow` that can update itself somewhere else in the code such as `updateFullWindow`.

Child component:

```
static get defaultProps(){
    return {
        fullWindow: false
    }
}
updateFullWindow = (value) => {
    this.setState({fullWindow: value});
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({fullWindow: nextProps.fullWindow});
}
```

I also have a `Parent` component that can update `fullWindow` and also other state properties.

Parent component:

```
fullScreenCallback = () => {
    this.setState({hideDetails: false});
}
clickCallback = () => {
    this.setState({fullWindow: true}));
} 
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={this.clickCallback}>Click Me</div>
            <Child {...this.state}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem I have is that the `componentWillReceiveProps` function is setting the `fullWindow` property on the `Child` state back to the prop default value value that was set in `defaultProps` and overwriting the `setState` in `updateFullWindow()`. This is because the `fullWindow` prop is being passed to `nextProps` when the other states get updated in the parent.

Basically I only want the child state `fullWindow` to change to the `nextProps` when the `clickCallback` has been run and explicitly changed the `fullWindow` property.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually worked in the end was removing the setStates and instead passing down a function from the parent that updated the parents states and calling this in the child component. This way you can always guarantee that the value will be up to date, i.e parent props changes won't overwrite your child state or visa versa.

E.G:

Parent component:

```
updateOptions = (newOptions) => {
    this.setState({options: newOptions});
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={this.clickCallback}>Click Me</div>
            <Child {...this.state} updateOptions={this.updateOptions}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Child component:

```
updateFullWindow = (value) => {
    this.props.updateOptions({fullWindow: value});
}

//Remove the componentWillReceiveProps
```

See here for more info on this pattern: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/is-this-a-decent-pattern-to-update-parent-state-from-children/560

Answer (score 0):

So, you could have something in your child component, if I'm reading this correctly like this

```
toggleFull() {
    this.setState({fullscreen: !this.state.fullscreen})
}

render() {
  const shouldFull = (this.state.fullscreen != null && this.state.fullscreen)
    || this.props.fullscreen
  return shouldFull ?
    <FullScreen /> : <NotFullScreen />
}
```

This will set it to fullscreen if state is set to fullscreen, but if
`state.fullscreen` hasn't been set, it will use this.props.fullscreen.

Also, `this.props.fullscreen` will basically default to `false`, because undefined will be `false`.

Also, use the `toggleFull` function for an `onClick` event, which I just didn't bother to write out.

Then, in your parent component, do something like this

`<Child fullscreen={this.state.fullscreen} />`